# Woocommerce show subcategory thumbnail on category page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

On the category page there are different products in the same category which are assigned to a subcategory. Below a single product I want to show the thumbnail of the subcategory which the product is assigned to. I've used this code to show the thumbnail:

```
    <?php 
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $thumbnail_id ); 
    ?>
```

The result is that is shows the thumbnail of the parent category (the category where all these products are in) instead of the subcategory thumbnail.

See here: http://www.solar-discounter.nl/product-categorie/panelen/

I hope someone has the answer for me, thanks in advance.

Comment: That's a whole different plugin, is this one more editable for personalization? It would be a shame to start all over again with this webshop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solved it!

I replaced the code with the following:

```
<?php
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    foreach ( $terms as $term ){
        $category_name = $term->name;
        $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
        echo '<img src="'.$image.'">';
    }
?>
```

Thanks to Filespit @ StackExchange

(https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/87950/show-category-images-on-single-product-page-and-product-overview-page)

Answer (score 1):

The WooCommerce reference say to do this in themes/yourtheme/functions.php

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'woocommerce_category_image', 2 );
function woocommerce_category_image() {
    if ( is_product_category() ){
        global $wp_query;
        $cat = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
        $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
        $image = wp_get_attachment_url( $thumbnail_id );
        if ( $image ) {
            echo '<img src="' . $image . '" alt="" />';
        }
    }
}
```